# How to swap - slideToggle two objects the same time?

Tags: jquery

Currently we have the following jQuery to hide one option and show another. How can we give it a smoother transition where it slides/fades the old one up and slides/fades the new one in?

```
function pdi_click() {
if ($('#weekendpass').is(":checked") == true) {
    $('.pdioption2').hide('fast');
    $('input[name=pdinotattending]').attr('checked', false);

    $('.pdioption1').show('fast');

} else {
    $('.pdioption1').hide('fast');
    $('input[name=pdiattending]').attr('checked', false);
    $('.pdioption2').show('fast');

}
```

Please see jsfiddle to recommend jQuery suggestions.

http://jsfiddle.net/JoshSalway/8YSRm/

Comment: Using `slow`? http://jsfiddle.net/HU8Nu/

Comment: I don't really see a problem with what's there .. what do you mean by "smoother?"  It would also help out a lot if you could tell us what you're supposed to do on that page to get the animation to occur instead of forcing us to guess.

Comment: looks smooth to me. I kind of like the effect. You may want to be more specific about what you really want

Comment: You have tons of errors in your HTML like unclosed `</div>` elements, multiple `ID` elements and different-named `class`-names (ok, that's not an error but you have a strange use of classes). Immagine that in a room full of people there's two Josh and I scream "Josh"! which one will turn? :) `ID`s HAVE to be unique!

Comment: Then use `fadeOut` and `fadeIn`, answered your own question.. LOL

Comment: @roXon I understand we are just modifying previous code here. unclosed </div> is because I just put it up.

Comment: @Josh, all clear, but be aware of that! ;)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/JoshSalway/raqhY/ with fadeOut and fadeIn looks rubbish.. Because well you see..

Comment: hmm... you can either remove `fast`/`slow` altogether or the solution in this fiddle is also good else you can put `show` code as a callback to previous hide call like this http://jsfiddle.net/HU8Nu/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `slideToggle` with a callback specified for the complete function.

```
function pdi_click() {
    if ($('#weekendpass').is(":checked") == true) {
        $('.pdioption2').slideToggle('slow', function(){
            $('.pdioption1').slideToggle('slow');
        });
        $('input[name=pdinotattending]').attr('checked', false);
    } else {
        $('.pdioption1').slideToggle('slow', function(){
            $('.pdioption2').slideToggle('slow');
        });
        $('input[name=pdiattending]').attr('checked', false);
    }
    //add_cost(25);
    //update_cost();
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/8YSRm/2/

Comment: You where faster! but as you are using slidetoggle why not getting out the animations off the if condition?

Comment: Thanks Kevin, This is exactly what we we're after. :)

Answer (score 1):

Set your desired elements to CSS `position:absolute;` and use the `.fadeTo()` method

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HU8Nu/2/)**</kbd>

**CSS:**

```
.pdioption1, .pdioption2{
    position:absolute;  
}
```

**jQ:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // This is more like it!
});


function pdi_click() {
    if ($('#weekendpass').is(":checked") == true) {
        $('.pdioption2').fadeTo(800,0);
        $('input[name=pdinotattending]').attr('checked', false);

        $('.pdioption1').fadeTo(800,1);

    } else {
        $('.pdioption1').fadeTo(800,0);
        $('input[name=pdiattending]').attr('checked', false);
        $('.pdioption2').fadeTo(800,1);

    }
    //add_cost(25);
    //update_cost();
}
```

Comment: Isnt it simpler to use the callback function? if you now want to change the animation times... double work!

Comment: Thanks @roXon, that is the fade version. We we're after the slideToggle feature as suggested by Kevin (See Correct Answer)

Comment: I see the correct answer, but I also see the **question title**. Happy coding

Answer (score 1):

To make sure one animation completed. Animate next one as a callback:

http://jsfiddle.net/8YSRm/4/

```
$('.pdioption1').hide('fast',function(){
            $('input[name=pdiattending]').attr('checked', false);
            $('.pdioption2').show('fast');
});
```